# Why is our wireless guest network not redirecting users to the webauth login page?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, http, webauthn

I'm trying to figure out the cause for what I assume is a webauth error.
In our organization's wireless network we have a guest SSID that uses webauth. When you access the network you are supposed to be directed to an "Acceptable Use" TOS page. When you press the "Accept Button" you have access to the guest network.

The problem I'm noticing is that for a lot for users they aren't automatically redirected to the log in page when they open their browser. They just get a "Site can't be reached message". When troubleshooting the issue with my phone, I found that when I first open the Chrome browser on my phone, the default page is the T-Mobile home page, which my browser tries to go to, but instead of getting redirected to the webauth page I get the "Site can't be reached" message ( see figure 1 ). When I enter "google.com" in the Chrome address bar, instead of being redirected to the webauth page, I get another "Site can't be reached" message ( see figure 2 ). No matter how many times i try to refresh it still doesn't redirect to the webauth page. However there are some addresses that if I put in the address bar, it does redirect me to the webauth page. In the example in figure 3, I use "snopes.com" and my browser is directed to the webauth page, where I'm able to accept the TOS and get access to the guest network.

So why the different behavior depending on which website your browser tries to go to. Why am I redirected correctly when I try to go to "snopes.com", but not "google.com"?

I'd like to understand why this happens, because even though I have a work around, a lot of our customers just assume that the guest network doesn't work because they never get to the webauth page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unless the user is browsing to an unsecured (non-HTTPS) webpage, the redirect cannot work. So what you should investigate instead is why the hotspot detection built into all major operating systems (both mobile and desktop) does not pick up the redirect.

Comment: @DanielB  I assumed it was an issue with HTTPS, as I've noticed at other times I get a certificate warning and the browser warns that I could be under attack.  But, I don't have that issue when I use the address "snopes.com", which my browser shows is a secure address.  Is it because my browser tries port 80 first?